# Python, Selenium, Chrome: How to set driver location in Selenium 4.12

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

#### Use case scenario

Selenium 4.12 (Chrome driver) behind proxy authentication and **no access to github.io**.

#### Problem

Somewhere along the way, `executable_path` arg in `webdriver.Chrome` method was deprecated. Instead, `webdrive_manager.chrome` module tries to download chromedrive.exe. In order to select driver version, it access https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json which I can't access due to company policies, therefore throwing an error.

#### Question

How to pass `chromedriver.exe` path to `webdriver.Chrome()` with selenium 4.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Service](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/) class now to pass the `executable_path`

Refer the below code, this is how you can do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="C:/<fullpath>/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```