# Cant find chrome driver version : 122.0.6261.94?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]
How do I find the Chrome version recommended by the error but i can't find the same version in this link https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads. when I upload version 114.0.5735.90 or below 112.0.5615.49 it always fails and recommends using this version 122.0.6261.94
[please check my Python code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckZzq.png)

[image]

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium Manager downloads `chromedriver` to a specific location when needed, however, if Selenium Manager detects a `chromedriver` in a different location on your system PATH, then it assumes that's the one you want, and selenium uses it, even if it raises an error.

That means you can either delete the existing `chromedriver` (so that Selenium Manager works as expected), or you can use a Python Selenium framework (such as [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)) that handles driver management in a more reliable way:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver()
driver.get("https://selenium.dev")

# ...

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Download current stable chrome driver which is version `122.0.6261.94` from below path. And use this in your code while setting the driver path.

[Link to download current stable chrome driver](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable)

**UPDATE:** I see from your code that you are not setting the `chromedriver.exe` path manually, but selenium's built-in tool [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) is handling the drivers. For selenium manager to detect and use the matching driver as per your Chrome browser, just clear/delete all the existing/old chromedrivers from your local cache(below location).

[image]

Run the code again and selenium should automatically download and use the latest driver to launch the browser.

Alternately, if you want to set the driver path manually, you need to use [Service Class](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/). Download the latest driver from the above provided link and refer answer in the below link to understand how to set driver path manually using Service class.

[How to set driver executable path in Python Selenium using Service Class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77143947/7598774)

Comment: That's not an actual answer. For all you know the driver is already downloaded. `use this` how?. Be very careful when you edit questions too. You can easily make things much worse

Comment: Point noted. And updated the answer with more explanation.