# webdriver.chrome doesnt give me executable_path as an argument what could be wrong

Tags: selenium-webdriver

trying to scrap job from a website and locating element by class_name got the class name but nothing is showing on my console when i run the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import  time
import pandas as pd
import os   

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


website = "https://vanhack.com/jobs"
driver_path = "/Users/Backdoor/Desktop/12projects/vanhack/chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=browser)


content = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lline-number')
```

Comment: Just let Selenium WebDriver locate the correct driver for you. Don't specify one.

Comment: Refer this answer to set the executable path using Service class- https://stackoverflow.com/a/77143947/7598774. Refer this answer to let selenium do the driver management instead of you setting the driver manually- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76463081/7598774

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes don't even use the `website` variable. You can try to use these codes to fetch the content you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

website = "https://vanhack.com/jobs"
options = Options()
# you can optionally use headless mode via the options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(), options=options)
driver.get(website)
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
content = soup.find('div', class='lline-number')
```